# Is this RAM overclocking?

Tags: memory, motherboard, overclocking, voltage, ddr

I have 2 DDR4 sticks (2x16 GB) running with a 3700X Ryzen CPU with an [MSI B450M Mortar Max motherboard](https://fr.msi.com/Motherboard/B450M-MORTAR-MAX/Overview):

- one 2x16 GB Crucial rated at XMP 3200 MHz CL16 18-18-36-72 at 1,35V
- one 2x16 GB rated at XMP 3600 MHz CL18 22-22-42-64 at 1,35V

[image]
[image]

Note that the Crucial and Corsair sticks seems to have the same chips... I guess...

**Test to 3800 Mhz**
I have pushed the Crucial sticks to 3800 Mhz CL18 22-22-22-42
All other settings are set to their default value (mainly AUTO) in the motherboard UEFI.
They can run flawlessly at these specs at 1,35V.

I have pushed the Corsair sticks to 3800 Mhz CL18 22-22-22-42
All other settings are set to their default value (mainly AUTO) in the motherboard UEFI.
They can run flawlessly at these specs at 1,36V min.

By flawlessly I mean :

- Boot to Windows 10 x64 : OK
- 120mn of Prime95 with no error
- 4 passes of [Passmark MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) with no error

**Test to 3733Mhz**
I have pushed the Crucial sticks to 3733 Mhz CL16 18-18-18-38.
All other settings are set to their default value (mainly AUTO) in the motherboard UEFI.
They can run near flawlessly at these specs at 1,38V min, but with just some errors on the Memtest runs (less than a dozen). No problem with Prime95.

I haven't succeeded to make the Corsair sticks run at 3733 Mhz CL16 18-18-18-38.

**My question :**
As I don’t had to raise the voltage of the Crucial sticks compared to the XMP setting to get these perfs @3800, am I effectively overclocking them more than the XMP settings does ?

On my point of view, they are sold underclocked and doing this, I am just making them working at their real specs. But we are talking here about a 20% improvement in specs, not talking about latency improvement going from 3200 CL16 to 3800 CL18.

And do I stress them too much doing this more than making them run at their XMP settings. Is there any concern or problem I did not see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I don’t had to raise the voltage of the Crucial sticks compared to the XMP setting to get these perfs @3800, am I effectively overclocking them more than the XMP settings does?

The [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/overclocking) of overclocking is *"to modify a hardware component so as to increase the speed of that component beyond the specifications of the manufacturer."*

So, Yes.
It would be considered overclocking even if you did change the voltage.

> On my point of view, they are sold underclocked and doing this, I am just making them working at their real specs.

You are *not* making them work at their "real" specs. A memory module's *real* specs would be the [JDEC standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#Modules) it was built to be compliant with. Any configuration outside that is considered overclocked, or sometimes underclocked.

[XMP](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xmp) is an extension to the JDEC standard that provides a means for manufacturers to program additional non-standard configurations in the DIMM itself. XMP also allows for motherboards to automatically read these memory profiles and run the modules at overclocked configurations that are pre-determined by the manufacturer.

XMP modules can be **XMP Ready** or **XMP Certified** though.

**XMP Ready** modules do not come with any guarantee of stability, the brand just indicates that the module contains XMP settings. Some of the XMP settings provided with them *can* be unstable depending on the hardware they're used with.

**XMP Certified** modules are tested to *guarantee* that the memory will be stable for all of its XMP configurations on a board & CPU that supports those speeds too.

> And do I stress them too much doing this more than making them run at their XMP settings. Is there any concern or problem I did not see ?

All silicon chips are produced with some margin for acceptable performance. Manufacturers tend to ["bin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_binning) chips based on their performance and test results, so every batch of chips could see a different distribution of high and low quality chips ending up in each bin. Even after binning, those chips may be further tested and binned by the DIMM manufacturer for their own purposes.

Two **XMP Certified** products with the same chips can still perform differently. Whichever has the higher XMP speeds is likely built from the higher binned chips. In some cases the higher binned chips can be used to meet demand for a slower product, which would not be labelled or programmed with their maximum potential.

If you're lucky, you may have modules that can overclock higher than the *guaranteed* speed with no negative consequences.
If you're not lucky, you may damage those modules over time or they may become unstable at those speeds at any point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I can push them, surprisingly and with no effort, at 20% more that the XMP setting. That sounds to me to be a huge overclock. With a near 15% gain in use... I'm confused... What do you think about that ? Also, is there a way to guess if I have lucky or unlucky modules ? :)

Comment: @Oliver, There is no way to guess. But you can *test* the overclock yourself with CPU & memory benchmarks, memtest, etc. (Which is something you *should* be doing). Just don't go over 1.5V and the memory modules should be unharmed if they fail.

Comment: I did, it's in the question

Comment: @Oliver, Then you've already answered your own question. The only way to know about long-term failures is to wait and see.

Comment: Because you say that the modules can become unstable over time and be damaged, thing that any benchmark cannot see.

Comment: OK... wait and see... Brrrrr. It looks like I'm going to stick with the 3600 Certified ones :)

Comment: @Oliver, Also consider that the manufacturer warranty is the manufacturer's own guess of how long the *certified* XMP overclock will be stable, if the warranty were longer they would eat too much of the cost on replacing products. If you don't use the XMP profile you could void the warranty too.

Comment: Just to be sure... To overclock, you need to give the hardware a boost of power. That's in fact what happens when you use the XMP settings. But... here I push the modules 20% over their XMP settings without any impact on the inputed power. So... Why would they fail ? I mean : no more power, no more heat... What would fail ? If I use a too large pipe with a few water, I won't cause any damage to the pipe if I use it with the amount of water it can carry... ?

Comment: @Oliver, Raising the frequency without raising the voltage can lead to a higher frequency of read/write errors in the chips. The CPU or OS usually has some built-in fault tolerance for this and can handle an occasional error. When you raise the frequency, you get more errors, and at some threshold your OS or CPU just can't continue and crashes (BSOD). According to your question, you only tested your overclock for 2 hrs. The overclock may be unstable after running for 24+ hrs; That is the length of testing the *certified* XMP modules go through to be sure they are stable.

Answer (score 0):

The key here are the words **XMP Certified**.

Having designed more DDRx memory into systems than I care to remember, here is my take.

The modules have been tested (or at least characterised) for those XMP profiles by the manufacturer and will operate at those speeds with the applied voltage as specified; it is perfectly possible they *might* work at a slightly higher rate but that operation is *not guaranteed* especially when manufacturing variation is taken into acount.

Setting the voltage higher increases power dissipation, and as the devices warm up, the data output transitions will slow down (how much is very process dependent) so extended operation at the higher (non certified) settings could conceivably lead to higher errors over time.

The [DDR4 datasheet](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr4/4gb_ddr4_dram_2e0d.pdf) I am reading indicates the power rail to the device *may* be as high as 1.5V so 1.35V is within those ratings but note that 1.5V is the absolute maximum (where you are overstressing the part).

I would also note you are not really gaining much by pushing above the XMP certified speeds; due to the transaction nature of the DDR4 interface (and indeed all SDRAM devices) the majority of time is spent in setting up the transaction rather than the actual data burst.

Reducing the setup timings *may* work, but as noted, they are not guaranteed and indeed you *may* get severe burst errors (which will incur other timing issues to recover).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here, I don't have a sligh gain, but a near 20% in theory, and near 15% in use... So yes, I gain a lot "pushing" these DDR at 3800 Mhz.